# Monty Hall Problem simulation gives weird answers

Tags: python, monty-hall

I tried to simulate the Monty Hall problem in Python, and ended up with 66% probability after a few attempts.
However, the first incorrect attempts were more interesting, as they consistently gave a probability of 55% and 44% respectively.

Here's the code:

```
import random
from sys import argv

def hall_old():
    choices = [0]*3
    choices[random.randint(0,2)] = 1
    guess = random.randint(0,2)
    reveal = (random.randint(1,2)+guess)%3 # This gives ~55%
    reveal = 2 - guess # This gives ~44%
    if choices[reveal]==1:
        return hall()
    return choices[3-guess-reveal]==1

def hall(): # This gives 66%
    choices = [0]*3
    choices[random.randint(0,2)] = 1
    guess = 0
    for i in range(1,3):
        if choices[i]==0:
            reveal = i
            break
    return choices[3-guess-reveal]==1

def main():
    times = int(argv[1]) # times game is played
    correct = 0
    for i in range(0, times):
        if hall_old():
            correct += 1
    print str(correct * 100 / times) + '%'

main()
```

From what I understand, the function hall_old(), should still give 66% probability when run but for some reason, if you change the way you select the variable *reveal* then the probability changes.
Can anyone explain why this is occurring?

Comment: `for i in range(1,3)` - shouldn't that be `range(0,2)`? Also, shouldn't your `main` use only `range(1,times)` or alternatively divide by `times+1` to obtain the percentages?  Perhaps it's just my python skills and it would easier for me with readable C code ...

Comment: `hall_old()` seems to call `hall()` which may not be what you intended

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen 'for i in range(1,3)' is used because the upper limit, 3, is excluded. Hence, if guess = 0, then reveal would be 1 or 2. Same reason for range(0,times), as range(1,times) would iterate for (times-1). Thank you for your answer, it helped me understand what was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a perfect PRNG, `guess` in `hall_old` should be a uniformly distributed random number $\in\{0,1,2\}$.

With `reveal = (random.randint(1,2)+guess)%3`, it should accordingly be that `reveal` is uniformly distributed $\in\{0,1,2\}\setminus\{\text{guess}\}$. Note that in this case `3-guess-reveal` is simply the remaining third number (why non call it `other`?).
In $\frac13$ of all cases, you call `hall()`, which itself seems to return `true` with a probability $\frac 23$. In the remaing $\frac23$ of all cases (namely, when `reveal` is not the win), you return if `choice[other]` is true, which shold be so with probability $\frac12$. Hence we expect something like
$$\frac13\cdot \frac23 +\frac23\cdot \frac12=\frac 59. $$

If you use `reveal = 2-guess` instead, again in $\frac13$ of all cases you return `hall()` and in the other $\frac23$ of cases, you return if `\choice[1]`is true (as `guess+reveal` is definitely $2$). Note that this never the case if `guess` is $= 1$ (as it would already have been caught by the first `if`). Hence we expect something like
$$ \frac 13\cdot \frac 23+\frac 23\cdot \left(\frac 13\cdot 0+\frac 23\cdot \frac12\right)=\frac 49.$$